# IF ó SWITCH en MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, condiciones

tengo una duda y espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un formulario donde el usuario selecciona el curso que tomo y este se guarda en la Base de Datos, sin embargo cada curso tiene diferentes horas de duración, mi duda es si al momento de guardar el curso hay algún modo de que se seleccione la duración y se guarde automáticamente en la Base de Datos? Había pensado que con la condicional IF o SWITCH pero nunca he hecho algo así.

Esta es la imagen de algunos cursos y su duración, pero aun faltan cursos

[image: Cursos y duración]

Este es un fragmento del código HTML para seleccionar y guardar los cursos:

```
<label for="curso">Seleccionar curso*</label>
                <select name="curso" id="curso">
                    <option value="ISO 9001:2015 Sistemas de gestión de la calidad.">ISO 9001:2015 Sistemas de gestión de la calidad.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 14001:2015 Sistemas de gestión ambiental.">ISO 14001:2015 Sistemas de gestión ambiental.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 45001:2018 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad y salud en el trabajo.">ISO 45001:2018 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad y salud en el trabajo.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 28000:2007 Sistemas de gestión para la seguridad de la cadena de suministro.">ISO 28000:2007 Sistemas de gestión para la seguridad de la cadena de suministro.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 37001:2016 Sistemas de gestión antisoborno.">ISO 37001:2016 Sistemas de gestión antisoborno.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 39001:2012 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad vial.">ISO 39001:2012 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad vial.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 31000:2018 Gestión del Riesgo - Directrices.">ISO 31000:2018 Gestión del Riesgo – Directrices.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 21001:2018 Sistemas de gestión para organizaciones educativas.">ISO 21001:2018 Sistemas de gestión para organizaciones educativas.</option>
                    <option value="ISO 19011:2018 Directrices para la auditoría de los sistemas de gestión.">ISO 19011:2018 Directrices para la auditoría de los sistemas de gestión.</option>
                </select>
```

Fragmento PHP al momento de hacer mi insert en la base de datos:

```
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $nombre);
$apellido = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $apellido);
$curp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['curp']);
$curso = $_POST['curso'];
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);

$resultado = $conn->query("
    INSERT INTO datos_usuarios (
        nombre,
        apellido,
        curp,
        curso,
        email
    ) VALUES (
        '$nombre',
        '$apellido',
        '$curp',
        '$curso',
        '$email'
    )");
```

Comment: que son curp y curso? es raro que quieras guardar las horas, ya que ellas deberian estar en la tabla que tiene los cursos...

Comment: Son parte del formulario, se guardan los datos entre ellos curp y curso pero estos se muestran en el formulario, las horas no las pueden ver los usuarios solo se guarda en la base de datos para después generar un PDF

Comment: Si las horas estan en la base de datos, no seberias sacarlas de la tabla que tiene los cursos cuando las necesites?

Comment: No están guardadas en la base de datos, lo que yo quería es que al momento de el usuario dar clic al botón para enviar sus datos se registraran las horas en automático dependiendo del curso que tomo,pero no sé como hacerlo

Comment: Si es un ejercicio, ok.. pero si es algo real, eso deberia ser una tabla en la db. Y entonces no necesitas sacar las horas pq la tabla que guarda esa info y sabe las horas

Comment: Y cómo puedo buscar la información para guiarme en sacar información de otras tablas para mi select? Como te comento no he hecho nada igual y me es muy complicado hacerlo

Comment: 1/2 Te recomiendo que replantees seriamente la forma de concebir tu programa. Si trabajas con bases de datos es mejor diseñar tablas que respondan a las necesidades de la aplicación. En el caso de los cursos tener una tabla con las columnas: `id_curso, nombre, hora_inicio, hora_fin` te permitirá trabajar de forma cómoda. Usarías `id_curso` como `value`, `nombre` como texto de cada `option` y harías un cálculo automático entre `hora_inicio`, `hora_fin` para determinar la duración. El problema de tu actual diseño es que es muy pobre. Si por ejemplo te piden un informe sobre todos los cursos ....

Comment: pues haces un select que traiga esa informacion cuando la necesites... o sea, podes joinear las tablas cuando necesitas saber las horas para cada persona y curso... otra cosa que noto, es que si una persona hace mas de un curso, vas a guardar su nombre varias veces?

Comment: en el [chat] podemos ayudarte bastante mas.. aca parece haber muchos problemas de diseño

Comment: 2/2 ... que empiezan a las 8:00  o todos los cursos que duran 3 horas, o todos los cursos que contengan la palabra `Procesos`, etc, etc, etc. será imposible rendir tal informe. Aparte de eso, todo du código se simplificaría para cualquier tarea, incluida la que intentas hacer aquí, en esta pregunta, porque leerías los cursos de la BD y en base a esos datos construirías los `option`. Las bases de datos ofrecen enormes ventajas que no deberías desaprovechar.

Comment: Si al parecer se van a guardar varias veces su nombre si hace más de un curso, solo que aún no sé como hacer para  tener un mejor control :( , y voy a intentar hacer otra tabla con los cursos, y sobre el chat seria contigo o seria en general? Soy nueva en Stack Overflow..

Comment: @MayraXimenaVargas en el chat hay varias personas siempre.. aca te falta aprender sobre normalizacion de bases de datos... si no, te vas a encontrar con cosas peores que esta...

Answer (score -3):

Creo que ya he podido, realice esto pero no sé si sea correcto la manera en que lo hice, al final si me registra las horas dependiendo del curso que selecciona el curso...

```
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $nombre);
$apellido = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $apellido);
$curp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['curp']);
$curso = $_POST['curso'];

    if($curso == 'ISO 9001:2015 Sistemas de gestión de la calidad.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 14001:2015 Sistemas de gestión ambiental.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 45001:2018 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad y salud en el trabajo.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 28000:2007 Sistemas de gestión para la seguridad de la cadena de suministro.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 37001:2016 Sistemas de gestión antisoborno.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 39001:2012 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad vial.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 31000:2018 Gestión del Riesgo - Directrices.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 21001:2018 Sistemas de gestión para organizaciones educativas.'){
        $horas = '8 horas';
    }
    if($curso == 'ISO 19011:2018 Directrices para la auditoría de los sistemas de gestión.'){
        $horas = '16 horas';
    }

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);


/* Ahora podemos concatenar las cadenas con seguridad */
$resultado = $conn->query("
    INSERT INTO datos_usuarios (
        nombre,
        apellido,
        curp,
        curso,
        horas,
        email
    ) VALUES (
        '$nombre',
        '$apellido',
        '$curp',
        '$curso',
        '$horas',
        '$email'
    )");
```

Comment: Ojala no tengas mil cursos nunca :(... esa info deberia estar en una tabal, la misma que uses para construir el select en php...